# Computed property is only firing once

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a service called screen-size which has a property called width.
This property is the value of the window width and will update on a resize event.

This works fine. In a component, I have a computed property that I want to update when this value changes like so...

```
nameStyle: computed('screenSizeService.width', function()
{
    console.log('in computed');
    return this.getFontSize(2.5, 2, null, null, this.$())
}),
```

This is only running once at the beginning unless I do this...

```
nameStyle: computed('screenSizeService.width', function()
{
    this.get('screenSizeService.width');
    console.log('in computed');
    return this.getFontSize(2.5, 2, null, null, this.$())
}),
```

Then it runs correctly. The value of nameStyle has no direct relation to the screen width, but the container width which changes when the screen width changes.

This is why i read from the screen width.

Why would I need to get the value in order for it to work? Why wouldnt it just computed from when it changes and run that function?

Comment: ["A computed property will only recompute its value when it is consumed."](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/object-model/computed-properties/) where do you consume it?

Comment: oh ok. But what if I dont need its value? I just know when it changes, x needs to be updated

Comment: [observers](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/object-model/observers/) maybe (never used ember, so take my advice with caution) ...

Comment: I was considering using observers, just heard some bad things about them, ill give it a try anyway, thanks !

Comment: @RachelDockter, do not use the observers. Instead, you can use `events`, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to explain the case and will try to suggest some alternative solutions.

**Explanation**

[Ember Guides](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/applications/services/#toc_accessing-services) says:

> Injected properties are lazy loaded; meaning the service will not be instantiated until the property is explicitly called.

So if your application doesn't use a service, that service will not be instantiated until your application starts to use it.

Further, if you don't **explicitly call** a service in your component, your component will hold the proxy object until your first call/usage of the service. And this proxy is not the real service object.

So in the first render of the component, since you don't use `screenSizeService`, you'll keep to use the proxy object. So your computed cannot be recalculated when the real object changed.

But when you use/call that service, you'll start to use the real object, so your computed will be able bind to the changes of the real service object. In your 2nd code, this `touch` is happening with `this.get('screenSizeService.width');` line.

**Solution Alternatives**

1. The first alternative is: To touch to the service in your component's init/willRender etc. hooks. Such as:

```
  init() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    // The following line added to initialize the service reference
    this.get('screenSizeService.width');
  }
```

2. The second alternative is: To use `events`. See [Evented API](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/release/classes/Evented)
   Actually if you don't need to use a services property, but you need to receive a notification from that service; then `events` can fit well.

In your component you can define:

```
  init() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    this.get('screenSizeService').on('screenSizeChanged', ()=>{
      this.set('nameStyle', this.getFontSize(2.5, 2, null, null, this.$()))
    })
  }
```

and in your service you need to trigger it with: `this.trigger('screenSizeChanged')` whenever the width value changed.